# Assigning a windows logon script

Tags: windows, vbscript, wsh, windows-scripting

Beginner question - Trying to create a simple logon script that executes when a Windows user logs on and copies a file from one folder to another. The OS is Windows 7.

This [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315245) says that logon scripts should go into

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\Repl\Import\Scripts folder.
```

I do not seem to have that folder in my machine. I created it manually and pushed the vbs file in there.

I also opened up computer management and assigned the script to a user. This is a standalone machine and has no network logons.

Code itself is simple and it works when the file is run except it is not getting called during logon.

**Is this the right place to put the logon script? Am I doing something wrong.**

Eventually I would like to be able to assign the logon script in C# using DirectoryEntry's LogonScript property. Any suggestions in the right direction would be of great help.

Comment: Is this a domain logon script, or a logon script for local logons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows has 2 default locatations for local logon scripts:

- `%SystemRoot%\System32\Repl\Import\Scripts` for logon scripts [assigned via `lusrmgr.msc`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315245).
- `%SystemRoot%\System32\GroupPolicy\User\Scripts\Logon` for logon scripts [assigned via `gpedit.msc`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770908.aspx).

Both paths don't exist in a default installation and must be created by an administrator.

`lusrmgr.msc` seems to accept only scripts with paths relative to the default location. For scripts assigned via `gpedit.msc` you can choose any path you like.

A (local) logon script must be assigned to a profile by one of the abovementioned methods, otherwise it won't be called at logon.

Comment: It does not seem to like a full path. Keeps complaining that it can only take a relative path. When I specify the relative path (in this case the script is in the above mentioned directory) and click apply it does not give me any error. But it seems like the script does not get executed either. Also, even I give a wrong path in the user properties and click on apply it does not throw an error. Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Apparently `lusrmgr` only checks if the path is absolute or relative, not if it actually exists. And you can only choose an arbitrary location when assigning a logon script with a local policy. I corrected my answer.